# sandwich + mlogit: `Error in ef/X : non-conformable arrays` when using `vcovHC()` to compute robust/clustered standard errors

Tags: r, stata, multinomial, standard-error, mlogit

I am trying to compute robust/cluster standard errors after using `mlogit()` to fit a Multinomial Logit (MNL) in a Discrete Choice problem. Unfortunately, I suspect I am having problems with it because I am using data in `long` format (this is a must in my case), and getting the error `#Error in ef/X : non-conformable arrays` after `sandwich::vcovHC(  , "HC0")`.

---

### The Data

For illustration, please gently consider the following data. It represents data from 5 individuals (`id_ind` ) that choose among 3 alternatives (`altern`). Each of the five individuals chose three times; hence we have 15 choice situations (`id_choice`). Each alternative is represented by two generic attributes (`x1` and `x2`), and the choices are registered in `y` (`1` if selected, `0` otherwise).

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id_ind id_choice altern           x1          x2 y
1       1         1      1  1.586788801  0.11887832 1
2       1         1      2 -0.937965347  1.15742493 0
3       1         1      3 -0.511504401 -1.90667519 0
4       1         2      1  1.079365680 -0.37267925 0
5       1         2      2 -0.009203032  1.65150370 1
6       1         2      3  0.870474033 -0.82558651 0
7       1         3      1 -0.638604013 -0.09459502 0
8       1         3      2 -0.071679538  1.56879334 0
9       1         3      3  0.398263302  1.45735788 1
10      2         4      1  0.291413453 -0.09107974 0
11      2         4      2  1.632831160  0.92925495 0
12      2         4      3 -1.193272276  0.77092623 1
13      2         5      1  1.967624379 -0.16373709 1
14      2         5      2 -0.479859282 -0.67042130 0
15      2         5      3  1.109780885  0.60348187 0
16      2         6      1 -0.025834772 -0.44004183 0
17      2         6      2 -1.255129594  1.10928280 0
18      2         6      3  1.309493274  1.84247199 1
19      3         7      1  1.593558740 -0.08952151 0
20      3         7      2  1.778701074  1.44483791 1
21      3         7      3  0.643191170 -0.24761157 0
22      3         8      1  1.738820924 -0.96793288 0
23      3         8      2 -1.151429915 -0.08581901 0
24      3         8      3  0.606695064  1.06524268 1
25      3         9      1  0.673866953 -0.26136206 0
26      3         9      2  1.176959443  0.85005871 1
27      3         9      3 -1.568225496 -0.40002252 0
28      4        10      1  0.516456176 -1.02081089 1
29      4        10      2 -1.752854918 -1.71728381 0
30      4        10      3 -1.176101700 -1.60213536 0
31      4        11      1 -1.497779616 -1.66301234 0
32      4        11      2 -0.931117325  1.50128532 1
33      4        11      3 -0.455543630 -0.64370825 0
34      4        12      1  0.894843784 -0.69859139 0
35      4        12      2 -0.354902281  1.02834859 0
36      4        12      3  1.283785176 -1.18923098 1
37      5        13      1 -1.293772990 -0.73491317 0
38      5        13      2  0.748091387  0.07453705 1
39      5        13      3 -0.463585127  0.64802031 0
40      5        14      1 -1.946438667  1.35776140 0
41      5        14      2 -0.470448172 -0.61326604 1
42      5        14      3  1.478763383 -0.66490028 0
43      5        15      1  0.588240775  0.84448489 1
44      5        15      2  1.131731049 -1.51323232 0
45      5        15      3  0.212145247 -1.01804594 0
")
```

---

### The problem

Consequently, we can fit an MNL using `mlogit()` and extract their robust variance-covariance as follows:

```
library(mlogit)
library(sandwich)
mo <-  mlogit(formula = y ~ x1 + x2|0 , 
              method ="nr",  
              data =  df,
              idx  =  c("id_choice", "altern"))

sandwich::vcovHC(mo, "HC0")
#Error in ef/X : non-conformable arrays
```

As we can see there is an error produced by `sandwich::vcovHC`, which says that `ef/X` is non-conformable. Where `X <- model.matrix(x)` and `ef <- estfun(x, ...)`. After looking through [the source code on the mirror on GitHub](https://github.com/cran/sandwich/blob/39824702dada9466719a12af5cd16b6577b2482d/R/vcovHC.R#L15) I spot the problem which comes from the fact that, given that the data is in long format, `ef` has dimensions `15 x 2` and `X` has `45 x 2`.

---

### My workaround

Given that the show must continue, I am computing the robust and cluster standard errors *manually* using some functions that I borrow from [`sandwich`](https://github.com/cran/sandwich/blob/39824702dada9466719a12af5cd16b6577b2482d/R/sandwich.R#L10) and [I adjusted to accommodate the Stata's output.](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/p_robust.pdf)

---

#### > Robust Standard Errors

These lines are inspired on the [sandwich::meat()](https://github.com/cran/sandwich/blob/39824702dada9466719a12af5cd16b6577b2482d/R/sandwich.R#L10) function.

```
psi<- estfun(mo)
k <- NCOL(psi)
n <- NROW(psi)
rval <-  (n/(n-1))* crossprod(as.matrix(psi))
vcov(mo) %*% rval %*% vcov(mo)

#            x1         x2
# x1 0.23050261 0.09840356
# x2 0.09840356 0.12765662
```

Stata Equivalent

```
qui clogit y x1 x2 ,group(id_choice) r
mat li e(V)
symmetric e(V)[2,2]
            y:         y:
            x1         x2
y:x1  .23050262
y:x2  .09840356  .12765662
```

---

#### > Clustered Standard Errors

Here, given that each individual answers 3 questions is highly likely that there is some degree of correlation among individuals; hence cluster corrections should be preferred in such situations. Below I compute the cluster correction in this case and I show the equivalence with the Stata output of `clogit , cluster()`.

```
id_ind_collapsed <- df$id_ind[!duplicated(mo$model$idx$id_choice,)]
psi_2 <- rowsum(psi, group = id_ind_collapsed )

k_cluster <- NCOL(psi_2)
n_cluster <- NROW(psi_2)
rval_cluster <-  (n_cluster/(n_cluster-1))* crossprod(as.matrix(psi_2))
vcov(mo) %*% rval_cluster %*% vcov(mo)

#           x1        x2
# x1 0.1766707 0.1007703
# x2 0.1007703 0.1180004
```

Stata equivalent

```
qui clogit y x1 x2 ,group(id_choice) cluster(id_ind)
symmetric e(V)[2,2]
            y:         y:
            x1         x2
y:x1  .17667075
y:x2   .1007703  .11800038
```

### The Question:

I would like to accommodate my computations within the `sandwich` ecosystem, meaning not computing the matrices manually but actually using the `sandwich` functions. Is it possible to make it work with models in long format like the one described here? For example, providing the `meat` and `bread` objects directly to perform the computations? Thanks in advance.

---

PS: I noted that [there is a dedicated `bread` function in `sandwich` for mlogit](https://github.com/cran/sandwich/blob/39824702dada9466719a12af5cd16b6577b2482d/R/bread.R#L84), but I could not spot something like `meat` for `mlogit`, but anyways I am probably missing something here...

Comment: I find it strange that it doesn't work, because calling `sandwich(mo)` appears to work. Judging by the example for `sandwich`, this should be equal to `vcovHC(mo, type = "HC")`,  which does not work. I find it strange that it would be affected by your data (in long format), since it's using the score contributions and the asymptotic variance covariance matrix to work them out (you did so yourself). Does the mlogit object perhaps not return the scores but only the column sums of teh scores such that the dimensions are wrong?

Comment: Hi @edsandorf, thanks for your comment. I checked the scores functions, and those have the correct dimension `15 x 2`. However, what I think is causing the problem is the fact that [in an intermediate step](https://github.com/cran/sandwich/blob/39824702dada9466719a12af5cd16b6577b2482d/R/vcovHC.R#L23), the object `X <- model.matrix(x)` is computed, where `x` is the design matrix, which has the _""wrong""_ dimension `45 x 2` given the long format of the data.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. And given how it relies on the model matrix you might not be able to use the `sandwich` package. Is there a particular reason for why you can't write a wrapper around the "manual" solution you outlined above?

Comment: Thank you again @edsandorf for your reply. There is no reason not to wrap up the illustrated solution; this is how I am actually doing it now. However, it was surprisingly unfortunate given that in [the latest `sandwich` article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v095i01), `mlogit` is included as one of the model class that full fill the requirements for `sandwich` to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why vcovHC does not work for mlogit

The class of HC covariance estimators can just be applied in models with a single linear predictor where the score function aka estimating function is the product of so-called "working residuals" and a regressor matrix. This is explained in some detail in the Zeileis (2006) paper (see Equation 7), provided as `vignette("sandwich-OOP", package = "sandwich")` in the package. The `?vcovHC` also pointed to this but did not explain it very well. I have improved this in the documentation at http://sandwich.R-Forge.R-project.org/reference/vcovHC.html now:

> The function meatHC is the real work horse for estimating the meat of HC sandwich estimators - the default vcovHC method is a wrapper calling sandwich and bread. See Zeileis (2006) for more implementation details. The theoretical background, exemplified for the linear regression model, is described below and in Zeileis (2004). Analogous formulas are employed for other types of models, provided that they depend on a single linear predictor and the estimating functions can be represented as a product of “working residual” and regressor vector (Zeileis 2006, Equation 7).

This means that `vcovHC()` is not applicable to multinomial logit models as they generally use separate linear predictors for the separate response categories. Similarly, two-part or hurdle models etc. are not supported.

#### Basic "robust" sandwich covariance

Generally, for computing the basic Eicker-Huber-White sandwich covariance matrix estimator, the best strategy is to use the `sandwich()` function and not the `vcovHC()` function. The former works for any model with `estfun()` and `bread()` methods.

For linear models `sandwich(..., adjust = FALSE)` (default) and `sandwich(..., adjust = TRUE)` correspond to HC0 and HC1, respectively. In a model with `n` observations and `k` regression coefficients the former standardizes with `1/n` and the latter with `1/(n-k)`.

Stata, however, divides by `1/(n-1)` in logit models, see:
[Different Robust Standard Errors of Logit Regression in Stata and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367974/different-robust-standard-errors-of-logit-regression-in-stata-and-r). To the best of my knowledge there is no clear theoretical reason for using specifically one or the other adjustment. And already in moderately large samples, this makes no difference anyway.

*Remark:* The adjustment with `1/(n-1)` is not directly available in `sandwich()` as an option. However, coincidentally, it is the default in `vcovCL()` without specifying a `cluster` variable (i.e., treating each observation as a separate cluster). So this is a convenient "trick" if you want to get exactly the same results as Stata.

#### Clustered covariance

This can be computed "as usual" via `vcovCL(..., cluster = ...)`. For `mlogit` models you just have to consider that the `cluster` variable just needs to be provided once (as opposed to stacked several times in long format).

#### Replicating Stata results

With the data and model from your post:

```
vcovCL(mo)
##            x1         x2
## x1 0.23050261 0.09840356
## x2 0.09840356 0.12765662
vcovCL(mo, cluster = df$id_choice[1:15])
##           x1        x2
## x1 0.1766707 0.1007703
## x2 0.1007703 0.1180004
```